# Simplify first/last date of current quarter as variables

Tags: vba, excel

I feel like this should be possible with less lines. Am I missing a VBA function to make this easier?

```
Sub dates()
Dim sDay As String
Dim eday As String
Quarter = DatePart(q, Date)
If Quarter = 1 Then
    sDay = "1/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
    eday = "3/31/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
ElseIf Quarter = 2 Then
    sDay = "4/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
    eday = "6/30/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
ElseIf Quarter = 3 Then
    sDay = "7/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
    eday = "9/30/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
ElseIf Quarter = 4 Then
    sDay = "10/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
    eday = "12/31/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep:

```
Sub dates()
Dim sDay As String
Dim eDay As String
Dim Quarter As Integer

For Quarter = 1 To 4

    sDay = CStr(3 * (Quarter - 1) + 1) & "/1/" & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
    eDay = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("q", 1, CDate(sDay)))

    Debug.Print "Quarter : " & Quarter & vbTab & sDay & vbTab & eDay
Next

End Sub
```

Also note that in your code, `q` needs to be offset in double-quotes as a string literal, unless it is defined elsewhere as such.

```
Quarter = DatePart("q", Date)
```

Comment: Whoa... I clearly have a long way to go in grasping programming/VB. This will work great, thanks!

Also, I see that I would have needed the "q". It was removed from my project at the time as I was testing the above code for all 4 quarters with a constant.

Comment: No problem. Yes there's a lot you can do with the Date/Time functions, this one is a simple algorithm (and about as complicated as my brain is capable of comprehending!).  if this is a satisfactory answer, please mark as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Sub Qmonth()
Dim CMonth As Integer 'selected month from range
Dim CYear As Integer 'selected year from range

CMonth = Range("MonthO").Value
CYear = Range("YearO").Value

Select Case CMonth
Case 1 To 3
Debug.Print DateSerial(CYear, 1, 1)
Case 4 To 6
Debug.Print DateSerial(CYear, 4, 1)
Case 7 To 9
Debug.Print DateSerial(CYear, 7, 1)
Case 10 To 12
Debug.Print DateSerial(CYear, 10, 1)
End Select

End Sub